# Dynamically decide when to use vue router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a big web application which I am building with vuejs and laravel.
Along the way, I have to switch between

```
        <router-link></router-link> and <a></a> tags
```

so I build a template that I have a link on it I want it to automatically detect if vue `<router-view></router-view>`
is available otherwise just use the normal `href tag`

The below code is the function I have assigned to the click function but it turns out not to be working

```
      try {
        this.$router.push("/cart");
      } catch (error) {
        window.location.href = "/cart";
      }
    }
```

My question is 
is there any way I can dynamically detect the presence of vue router and as well decide on which tag to use. 
Either
 `window.location.href`
 or
`this.$router.push()`

Comment: I would give the template a prop called `mode` give the `mode` 2 states: `router` and `anchor` then based on the props you can  know. This can be done when you generate the template.

Comment: curiosity question: why do you need to know if `router-link` is available? `router-link` will always be available if you have it defined in your routes. Also `router-link` is used to internal links while `<a>` tags are used to outside links (although you can sue it to internal links as well)

Comment: Charlie because I just want to keep mounting the template anyway it's needed and as well give my users some cool navigation if Available.

Comment: Michael your comment is actually what I'll go with. It's a nice suggestion Just passing a prop to determine the way forward. Thanks @Michael